# How to know when the socket on the other side is closed

Tags: java, android, python, sockets

I have an android app(java) and a python "server", the android app connects to the python server through sockets. When I close the socket through java (socket.close()) the python program does not throw an exception like I excepted it to but when I close the android app (fully close) it throws "[Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" which is was I wanted it to do from closing it through the socket.

How can I know when the android app closed the socket without exiting the app itself?

python:

```
def __init__(self, IP, port):
        try:
            self.acceptor = socket.socket()
            self.acceptor.bind((IP, port))
            self.acceptor.listen(1)
        except socket.error, e:
            print e

def start_server(self):
    #Start server:
    try:
        self.sock, self.connecting_ip = self.acceptor.accept() 
        print self.connecting_ip[0] + " connected!"

    except socket.error, e:
        print e

def wait_for_command(self):
    stop_flag = True
    try:
        while stop_flag:
            data = self.sock.recv(1024)
            if data:
                data_tuple = self.split_msg(data)
                if data_tuple[0] == self.MSG_REQ:
                    print data_tuple[1]
                    stop_flag = False
    except socket.error, e
         print e
```

Comment: But the android app is NOT closing the socket; that happened on the server... or so you said.

Comment: If the socket got closed on the other side I think that the only way to know it is trying to send some information and catch an Exception.

Comment: Are you using UDP or TCP sockets?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch the android app did close the socket on it's end (can't send anything to the server anymore) yet the python server remains without knowing the other socket is closed.

Comment: Please reduce your programs to the smallest possible example that demonstrates the problem, and copy-paste those short programs into your question. See http://SSCCE.ORG for more information.

Comment: @Shay I see... no there is no discreet "disconnect"; your server may not detect it for some time - it'll retransmit packets in an attempt to be "reliable".

Comment: Try sending a specific message just before you close it. Otherwise the only thing you can do is to wait for the a request to hang for a long time.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - There certainly is a discreet disconnect event in TCP. It is any packet that has a FIN bit set, and is typically sent after a `.close()` or `.shutdown()` call.

Comment: @Robᵩ And if there isn't a packet with the FIN bit set?

Comment: @sweeneyrod Alright I'll do just that, I just wanted to know if there is another way besides actually telling the server that it's going to close now

Comment: If one side didn't send a FIN, but internally deleted its connection state, then subsequent packets sent to it should result in it sending an RST response.

Comment: @Shay - The situation you describe should not happen. If you close the connection on the Java client, the Python server should more-or-less immediately informed. If you provide a sample program, we can tell you why your program isn't behaving correctly.

Comment: @Robᵩ Well I added the python side of the socket, the java part is basically connecting to it and closing (socket.close()) on a button press (which works fine just doesn't tell the server)

Comment: As a side note, using a `stop_flag` like this just to avoid using `break` statements is not very Pythonic; it adds extra verbosity, and extra places to get something wrong. While there are arguable reasons to avoid `break` in some other languages (like pre-C99 C), in Python `break` is the idiomatic way to break out of a loop, and there are no down-sides to using it. (And giving the flag a name that implies the opposite sense from its actual use doesn't help…)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A blocking `recv` call returns `''` on EOF.

Your code handles that by completely ignoring it and going back to `recv` again. Which will immediately return `''` again, and you'll just infinitely loop on ignoring that EOF.

Just do this:

```
if data:
    # etc.
else:
    stop_flag = False
```

---

You may want to read a basic sockets tutorial, like the [Socket Programming HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html#using-a-socket), which explains this very early on:

> When a `recv` returns 0 bytes, it means the other side has closed (or is in the process of closing) the connection. You will not receive any more data on this connection. Ever.

… and shows a few different ways of dealing with it (depending on whether unsolicited shutdown from the other side is an expected way to say "we're done" or an unexpected error).